# How to create an AutoKey script that pastes from clipboard?

Tags: autokey

Before switching to Ubuntu I used to use AutoHotkey for the sole purpose of pasting from my clipboard, the simple command was:

```
 ~f2::
clipboard = %clipboard%
send %clipboard% {enter}
```

or something along those lines. Does anyone have a similar script for Autokey?

Answer (score 5):

I've found that we can do it by script like this:

```
content = clipboard.get_clipboard()
keyboard.send_keys("wrapping text %s wrapping text" % content)
```

Then the script can be used by an abbreviation or a hotkey which you can set on it.

Comment: This is different than pasting from the clipboard. Instead, it is typing what is in the clipboard. This doesn't always work for me; it sometimes loses keystrokes in remote RDP sessions. How can you instead automate pasting the whole clipboard contents at once, without having to press ctrl-v yourself?

Comment: Nowadays I think you can try Powertoys program for Windows 10+. It's just a guess, but recently I successfully used it as a keyboard remapper, maybe it has some clipboard managing capabilities too

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for Windows, but what about Linux?

Comment: @LonnieBest Did you find a better linux solution?

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki - You can fill the clipboard using `clipboard.fill_clipboard(stringName)`, and then press ctrl-v to paste what's in the clipboard as a whole instead of sending each individual key like `keyboard.send_keys()` does. I never figured out a way to make Autokey paste from the clipboard without typing ctrl-v myself. If you know how, please tell me.

Comment: @LonnieBest Added an answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1434833/24458

Comment: @LonnieBest The reason the above (wrong) answer doesn't behave as expected is because the API call is asynchronous and returns immediately before it has actually done anything. The simple fix for this is to add a delay after any clipboard API call with something like `time.sleep(0.1)`. Interspersing delays in your scripts tends to solve a lot of problems, especially with applications that can't accept input as fast as AutoKey can send it.

Answer (score 1):

```
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+v")
```

Also, for phrases, be sure to select this option:

[image]

Comment: Phrases aren't involved here, but when you do use them, the above option should always be your first choice unless your phrase contains macros such as `<down>` or `<cursor>`. As of AutoKey 0.96.0, this is the default for new phrases as it avoids a lot of potential probems.